# Is there a way i could keep track of the Time and the entity that was changed in a model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Basically I'm trying to get the time and the entity changed in a particular model when ever the update method is called.

This is my model I want to keep track of:

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");

 const modelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     user: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User",
     },
     name: {
         type: String,
         required: true,
     },
     note1: String,
     note2: String,
     note3: String,
     images: {
         type: Array,
         required: true
     },
     status: {
         enum: ['draft', 'pending_quote', 'pendong_payment', 'in_production', 'in_repair', 'pemding_my_review', 'fulfilled'],
         type: String,
         default: "draft"
     },
     price: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Price",
     }
 }, {
     timestamps: true,

 })


 module.exports = mongoose.model("Model", modelSchema)
```

And this is the method I call to update the status:

```
exports.updateModel = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let id = req.params.id;
        let response = await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {
            new: true
        })
        res.status(200).json({
            status: "Success",
            data: response
        })

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err,
            msg: "Something Went Wrong"
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: which fields you want to save the date and entity details in?

Comment: i could create a `changes` array to store them

Comment: ive posted an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

you can add a new field in your schema like:

```
logs:[{
        entity: String,
        timeStamp: Date
        
    }]
```

Then updating it basing on your current code:

```
let id = req.params.id;
 // I don't know whats in the req.body but assuming that it
 // has the correct structure when passed from the front end

 let response = await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, 
      {
       $set:req.body,
       $push:{logs:{entity:'your entity name here',timeStamp:new Date()}}
       }, {
       new: true
      })
```

Comment: I actually want this to be automated, in the sense that once the status is updated, its pushes the updated status and the time into the logs array.

Comment: Doing this ` req.body.logs.push({
            entity: status,
            timeStamp: new Date()
        })` says push is undefined

Comment: This is how i am making my request in POSTMAN :`{
 "status":"pending_quote"
}`

Comment: so if you console.log(req.body) it will show : {"status":"pending_quote" } ?